# Revert CAST(0xABCD AS date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I am designing a query to build an insert query from parts of the data that is in a database.

I know that you can export the whole database using SQL Server Management Studio, but I only need a part, and I need it in an automated form.

The Insert query that SSMS generates for a certain dataset would be

```
INSERT INTO tbl (dateCol) VALUES(CAST(0xABCD AS Date))
GO
```

and I am now trying to cast the date inserted by this statement back to 0xABCD.

I don't know what type 0xABCD is, so I played around:

- Casting to int returns `Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed` error
- Casting to string returns ISO format, but not 0xABCD format.

Could I use ISO format from casting to string? If so, why did MS choose to use some kind of hex values with CAST, instead of universally understandable ISO date, in its own SSMS export routine?

Comment: I am bit confused. Where are you getting the hex values from?

Comment: The hex values are produced by the MS SSMS export function. I edited the original question to that effect.

Comment: Meaning you used SSMS, right clicked the database Tasks -> Export Data? Or something else?

Comment: `SELECT CAST(0xABCD AS Date)` -> `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(0xABCD AS INT) AS DATETIME)
```

-- 2020-06-01 00:00:00.000

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST('2020-06-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS INT) AS BINARY(2))
```

-- 0xABCD